Nestjs GraphQL validate @InputType before processing Guard?
I setup graphql & a app guard for my nestjs project, but has some problem with the process order of request.
This is my dto input for create a Post object
import { InputType, Field } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { IsNotEmpty, IsNumber } from 'class-validator';

@InputType()
export class CreatePostDto {
    @Field()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    title: string;

    @Field()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    content: string;

    @Field()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsNumber()
    authorId: number;
}

First i try to set authorId as string "4" it return like this
It return the error of input
But i expect it to return unauthorized error (exception throw in app guard). This is full output
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Float cannot represent non numeric value: \"4\"",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 72
          }
        ],
        "extensions": {
          "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
          "stacktrace": [
            "GraphQLError: Float cannot represent non numeric value: \"4\"",
            "    at GraphQLScalarType.parseLiteral (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\graphql\\type\\scalars.js:169:13)",
            "    at isValidValueNode (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\graphql\\validation\\rules\\ValuesOfCorrectTypeRule.js:177:30)",
            "    at Object.StringValue (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\graphql\\validation\\rules\\ValuesOfCorrectTypeRule.js:141:28)",
            "    at Object.enter (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\graphql\\language\\visitor.js:301:32)",
            "    at Object.enter (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\graphql\\utilities\\TypeInfo.js:391:27)",
            "    at visit (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\graphql\\language\\visitor.js:197:21)",
            "    at validate (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\graphql\\validation\\validate.js:91:24)",
            "    at processGraphQLRequest (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\@apollo\\server\\src\\requestPipeline.ts:246:40)",
            "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
            "    at internalExecuteOperation (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\@apollo\\server\\src\\ApolloServer.ts:1331:12)"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

The auth guard is set as the APP_GUARD and still work well when i post right input( authorId is 4 as number)
It return exception of guard
this is full output
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unauthorized",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createPost"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
        "stacktrace": [
          "UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized",
          "    at AuthGuard.canActivate (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\src\\common\\guards\\auth.guard.ts:35:10)",
          "    at GuardsConsumer.tryActivate (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\core\\guards\\guards-consumer.js:15:34)",
          "    at canActivateFn (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\core\\helpers\\external-context-creator.js:155:59)",
          "    at target (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\core\\helpers\\external-context-creator.js:73:37)",
          "    at Object.createPost (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\core\\helpers\\external-proxy.js:9:30)",
          "    at field.resolve (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\@apollo\\server\\src\\utils\\schemaInstrumentation.ts:82:22)",
          "    at executeField (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\graphql\\execution\\execute.js:492:20)",
          "    at D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\graphql\\execution\\execute.js:377:22",
          "    at promiseReduce (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\graphql\\jsutils\\promiseReduce.js:23:9)",
          "    at executeFieldsSerially (D:\\Code\\NodeJS\\fstack\\backend\\node_modules\\graphql\\execution\\execute.js:373:43)"
        ],
        "originalError": {
          "message": "Unauthorized",
          "statusCode": 401
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}


It seem that graphql validate inputType for graphql query process before the app guard. Is that a bug or i use it wrong
